# Проблема в сайте для блога. Django

Tags: python, django

У меня сайт для блога.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render


def index(request):
    latest_articles_list = Article.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[-5]
    return render(request, 'articles/list.html', {'latest_articles_list': latest_articles_list})

def detail(request, article_id):
    try:
        a = Article.objects.get(id=article_id)

    except Article.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404('Проект не найден')

    latest_comment_list = a.comment_set.order_by('-id')[10]

    return render(request, 'articles/detail.html', {'article': a, 'latest_comment_list': latest_comment_list})


def leave_comment(request, article_id):
    try:
        a = Article.objects.get(id=article_id)

    except Article.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404('Проект не найден')

    a.comments_set.create(author_name=request.POST['name'], comment_text = request.POST['text'])

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('articles:detail', args=(a.id,)))
```

detail.html

```
{% extends base.html %}


{* block title *}{{article.project_title}}{* endblock *}

{* block content *}

<h2>{{article.project_title}}</h2>

<p>{{article.project_text}}</p>
<em>{{article.project_data}}</em>

<hr>

{% if latest_comment_list %}

    {% for c in latest_comment_list %}
        <p>
            <strong>{{c.author_name}}</strong>
            <p>{{c.comment_text}}</p>
        </p>
    {% endfor %}

{% else %}
    Еще не кто не оценил! Будьте первым!
{% endif %}

<hr>

<form action="{% url 'articles:leave_comment' article.id %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" required placeholder="Ваше имя" name="name"><br>
    <textarea name="text" required placeholder="Очень интересно и круто!" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea><br>

    <button type="submit">Оставить комментарий</button>
</form>
{* endblock *}
```

urls.py (судя по ошибке, проблема тут)

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'articles'
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name = 'index'),
    path("<int:article_id/>", views.detail, name = 'detail'),
    path("<int:article_id/leave_comment/>", views.leave_comment, name = 'leave_comment')
]
```

Но это не увенчалось успехом:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: URL route '<int:article_id/>' uses parameter name 'article_id/' which isn't a valid Python identifier.
```

Я поискал проблему тут, но все что я нашел это была проблема уже исправленная у меня (но если быть точнее не сделанная).
И еще если может понадобится models.py:

```
import datetime

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Article(models.Model):
    article_title = models.CharField("Проект", max_length = 15)
    article_text = models.TextField("текст проекта")
    article_k = models.ImageField('Изображение')
    final_text = models.CharField("Конец", max_length = 20)
    article_video = models.ImageField('Видео')
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('дата публикации')

    def __str__(self):
        return  self.project_title

    def ws(self):
        return self.project_data >= (timezone.now - datetime.timedelta(days=7))


class Comment(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete= models.CASCADE)

    author_name = models.CharField('имя автора', max_length = 50)
    comment_text = models.CharField('текст комментария', max_length = 500)

    def __str__(self):
        return  self.author_name
```

версия 5.0.3 (Django)

Comment: научитесь оформлять вопрос - проверяйте, что у вас получается в итоговом виде, чтобы не пропадали некоторые строки. и самое главное - научитесь правильно вопрос формулировать. ничерта же не понятно.